# What is the purpose of the ArgMin and ArgMax type synonyms in Data.Semigroup?

Tags: haskell, monoids, argmax, semigroup, type-synonyms

The [`base`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/) library in Haskell has the following type synonyms in [`Data.Semigroup`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Semigroup.html):

```hs
type ArgMin a b = Min (Arg a b)

type ArgMax a b = Max (Arg a b)
```

Here are links to the haddocks: [`ArgMin`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Semigroup.html#t:ArgMin) and [`ArgMax`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Semigroup.html#t:ArgMax)

**What is the purpose of these two type synonyms?  Where can they be used effectively?**

It might be helpful to include an explanation of what the argmin and argmax functions do in mathematics, and how that is related to these type synonyms.

---

Here's a little extra information so you don't have to jump to Hackage.

Here's the definition of [`Arg`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Semigroup.html#t:Arg):

```hs
-- | 'Arg' isn't itself a 'Semigroup' in its own right, but it can be
-- placed inside 'Min' and 'Max' to compute an arg min or arg max.
data Arg a b = Arg a b
```

Its doc string suggests that `ArgMin` and `ArgMax` can be placed inside of `Min` and `Max` to compute an arg min or an arg max.

[`Min`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Semigroup.html#t:Min) and `Max` look like the following:

```hs
newtype Min a = Min { getMin :: a }
```

The `Semigroup` instance is interesting:

```hs
instance Ord a => Semigroup (Min a) where
  (<>) = coerce (min :: a -> a -> a)
```

It looks like it is using `min` as `(<>)`.

We can look at what the `Ord` instance looks like for `Arg`, since it is relevant here:

```hs
instance Ord a => Ord (Arg a b) where
  Arg a _ `compare` Arg b _ = compare a b
  min x@(Arg a _) y@(Arg b _)
    | a <= b    = x
    | otherwise = y
  max x@(Arg a _) y@(Arg b _)
    | a >= b    = x
    | otherwise = y
```

This appears to only run the comparison on the first type argument to `Arg`.

Comment: To obtain the minimum item (*arg*), according to some attribute, and not the element itself.

Comment: I had the same question a few months ago, but struggled to find good examples. The haddocks were improved since (https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/merge_requests/2911, https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/merge_requests/2950), but I'm sure they could be improved further.

Comment: Those type synonyms aren't useful. If the documentation for `Arg` is insufficient, it should be expanded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose it's one of those things that exist in Haskell because the theoretical concept exists. I'm not sure if these types have much practical use, but they do illustrate just how extensive the concepts of semigroups and monoids are in relation to programming.

Imagine, for example, that you need to pick the longest of two names, `name1` and `name2`, both of them `String` values. You can use the `Semigroup` instance of `ArgMax` for that:

```
Prelude Data.Semigroup> Max (Arg (length name1) name1) <> Max (Arg (length name2) name2)
Max {getMax = Arg 5 "Alice"}
```

After that, it's just a question of unwrapping `"Alice"` from its container.

As Willem Van Onsem points out in the comments, you can use `ArgMax` and `ArgMin` to pick the maximum or minimum item, according to some attribute of the item, but still keeping the original item around.

Comment: I have used it in real code before. We wanted to implement an allocator-like thing, where it was easy to add blocks of space back to the pool and grab the largest block of space from the pool (but there was more information about blocks that we wanted to ignore in the comparisons). We used an existing heap implementation with `ArgMax`; done. Another way to look at it: it's essentially the decorate-sort-undecorate pattern, but for min/max instead of sort.

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of them is to implement things like `minimumOn`:

```hs
minimumOn :: (Ord b, Foldable f) => (a -> b) -> f a -> Maybe a
minimumOn f = fmap (getArg  . getMin)
            . getOption
            . foldMap (Option . Just . Min . (Arg =<< f))
            --                         ^^^^^^^^^^
            --                           ArgMin
  where
    getArg (Arg _ x) = x
```

While this implementation might look a little convoluted, it's often helpful to implement things using general concepts like monoids. For instance, in this case, it is straightforward to adapt the above code to compute the min and max in a single pass.

Answer (score 3):

I reach for `ArgMin` / `ArgMax` when:

- I want to compute (a function of) the minimum/maximum of some values according to a comparison function
- The comparison is *costly* or *unwieldy* to recompute, so I want to cache its result; and/or
- I want to do it monoidally with `foldMap` instead of with an explicit/specialised `minimumBy` / `maximumBy` or `sortOn`, to leave it flexible to changes in the future such as a different monoid or parallelisation

Here’s an adaptation of a recent real-world example from my job, `findNextWorkerQueue`, which takes a map from workers to tasks and finds the worker with the earliest first task, e.g. given this input:

- Worker 1:

  - Time 10: Task A
  - Time 12: Task B
  - Time 14: Task C
- Worker 2:

  - Time 5: Task D
  - Time 10: Task E
  - Time 15: Task F
- Worker 3:

  - Time 22: Task G
  - Time 44: Task H

It would produce a start time of 5, and a work queue describing worker 2, with a first task of D, and subsequent tasks of E & F.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Data.Map       (Map)
import Data.Semigroup (Arg(..), Min(..), Option(..))
import Data.Sequence  (Seq(Empty, (:<|)))

import qualified Data.Map as Map

-- An enumeration of computation units for running tasks.
data WorkerId = …

-- The timestamp at which a task runs.
type Time = Int

-- Some kind of task scheduled at a timestamp.
data Scheduled task = Scheduled
  { schedAt   :: !Time
  , schedItem :: !task
  }

-- A non-empty sequence of work assigned to a worker.
data WorkQueue task = WorkQueue
  { wqId    :: !WorkerId
  , wqFirst :: !(Scheduled task)
  , wqRest  :: !(Seq (Scheduled task))
  }

-- | Find the lowest worker ID with the first scheduled task,
-- if any, and return its scheduled time and work queue.
findNextWorkerQueue
  :: forall task
  .  Map WorkerId (Seq (Scheduled task))
  -> Maybe (Time, WorkerQueue task)
findNextWorkerQueue
  = fmap getTimeAndQueue . getOption
  . foldMap (uncurry minWorkerTask) . Map.assocs
  where

    minWorkerTask
      :: WorkerId
      -> Seq (Scheduled task)
      -> Option (Min (Arg (Time, WorkerId) (WorkQueue task)))
    minWorkerTask wid tasks = Option $ case tasks of
      Empty -> Nothing
      t :<| ts -> Just $ Min $ Arg
        (schedTime t, wid)
        WorkQueue { wqId = wid, wqFirst = t, wqRest = ts }

    getTimeAndQueue
      :: Min (Arg (Time, WorkerId) (WorkQueue task))
      -> (Time, WorkQueue task)
    getTimeAndQueue (Min (Arg (time, _) queue))
      = (time, queue)
```

(Note that this is using `Option` to support GHC 8.6; in GHC ≥8.8, `Maybe` has an improved `Monoid` instance depending on `Semigroup` instead of `Monoid`, so we can use it with `Min` without imposing a `Bounded` constraint. The time signatures are just for clarity here.)